# Android: Unable to get ID from GCMRegistrar

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Hey guys I am trying to implement GCM in my app. However I am unable to get an ID back no matter what I do. Here is my code so far:

**GCMIntenServices**

```
public class GCMIntenServices extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

    /**
     * Method called on Receiving a new message
     * */

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

        Toast.makeText(context,"Message Received which means Alex is GOD!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);

    }

    //Display an error message in case of failure
    @Override
    protected void onError(Context context, String s) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"Something went wrong!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    /**
     * Method called on device registered
     **/
    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String s)
    {
        GCMServerUtilities.register(context,"151603048070");
    }

    /**
     * Method called on device un registered
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String s) {}

    /**
     * This method creates the notification to notify the user that the server had sent a message to him.
     */
    private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message)
    {
        //TODO: Make it look proper. This is just a test look.
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Home.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
}
```

**GCMServerUtilities**

```
public class GCMServerUtilities
{
    private static final int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 5;
    private static final int BACKOFF_MILLI_SECONDS = 2000;
    private static final Random random = new Random();

    /**
     * Register this account/device pair within the server.
     *
     */
    public static void register(final Context context, String regId)
    {
        long backoff = BACKOFF_MILLI_SECONDS + random.nextInt(1000);
        // Once GCM returns a registration id, we need to register on our server
        // As the server might be down, we will retry it a couple
        // times.
        for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_ATTEMPTS; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                GCMRegistrar.register(context,regId);

                return;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Here we are simplifying and retrying on any error; in a real
                // application, it should retry only on unrecoverable errors
                // (like HTTP error code 503).

                if (i == MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
                    break;
                }
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(backoff);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    // Activity finished before we complete - exit.
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    return;
                }
                // increase backoff exponentially
                backoff *= 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Main Activity**

```
 //GooglePlay Services Check
    if (checkPlayServices())
    {
        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);


        //get the registered ID
        regid = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(context); //this returns ALWAYS NULL

        if (regid.isEmpty()) {
            //If the regID is empty try to register again!
            registerInBackground();
        } else {
            regid = GCMPreferences.getRegistrationId(context);
        }
    }
private void registerInBackground() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                }
                try {
                    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(context);
                    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(context);
                }catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                GCMServerUtilities.register(context,SENDER_ID);

              /*  Constants.registration_id = regid;
                Log.d(TAG, "########################################");
                Log.d(TAG, "#   Registration ID= " + regid);
                Log.d(TAG, "########################################");
                SharedPreferences pref = getGCMPreferences();
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regid);
                editor.commit();*/
                return null;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(Constants._TAG, e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }

    }.execute();
}
```

And finally my manifest:

```
 <!-- Needed for GCM -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<permission
    android:name="in.android.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="in.android.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

  <application
  <!-- [START gcm_receiver] -->
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.gcmapp.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.gcmapp.gcm.GCMIntenServices"/>
    <!-- [END gcm_receiver] -->
 application/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's because GCMRegistrar is deprecated. Use Instance ID API instead. Check out official docs: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register.

Comment: `GCM` might already have been obsoleted ...meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

GCM is deprecated.
You can use Firebase Messaging for Push Notification.

If you are using Android studio 3.0 or up you can go to Tools and click on Firebase.
You can than integrate any firebase service by clicking on few steps only.

[image]